# angular webpage resource not found

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html5-audio

so basically i'm trying to play some music from the ts file (working with angular) using the Audio type, on the src property I specified what I'm convinced to be the correct path, here's the code:

```
playMusic(){
console.log("Playing music");
let audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "./home_music.mp3";
audio.loop = true;
audio.load();
audio.play();
}
```

I put that path because the mp3 file is in the same folder as the ts file, only the browser gives me this error:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/homeMusic.mp3 404 (Not Found)
```

and it actually makes sense because the file isn't in that path, it's in `/src/app/home/homeMusic.mp3`, (I used ./file.jpeg in the CSS file to set a background image and it worked just fine but here apparently not)

of course I tried putting the whole relative path but I still get that error, any suggestions?

Comment: It should be in the `/assets` folder. All assets should be. That's where Angular will be looking for static files. Also I believe the path should be "home_music.mp3" or "/assets/home_music.mp3", without the `./`

Comment: just tried it, still doesn't work, I don't think I inserted the wrong path becuse I mouse clicked on "copy relative path", I also swapped the backslashes with normal slashes, before trying that I also put a backslash before each backslash since that character also means "ignore the next character" or something like that so by their own they messed up the path

Answer (score 1):

solved it, just put it in the assets folder and navigate to it, for me the path was "../../assets/whatever.mp3"

Comment: Yo don't need relative path to assets, just use `/assets/bla.mp3`

Comment: true. (need more caracters to post reply lmao)